# PHP $_POST receives no data

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the form below which has 13 inputs including a file input:

```
<form class="form-signin align-items-center" id="register" method="post" action="/services/phpqueries/registerProvider.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input  type="text" id="companyName" class="form-control"  placeholder="Nombre de la Empresa"  required autofocus >
<textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="4" placeholder="Descripción de Servicios" required autofocus  ></textarea>
<textarea class="form-control" id="cost" rows="3" placeholder="Costo de servicios puede usar rangos" required autofocus ></textarea>
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="photo"> 
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" required autofocus>
<input style="margin:0px" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña"  required autofocus>
<input  type="text" id="nameC" class="form-control"  placeholder="Nombre" required autofocus>
```

and the PHP code I call to process this form is the one below:

```
print "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'];
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
print "DATA: <pre>";
var_dump($data);
var_dump($_POST, $_FILES);
if(isset($_POST['companyName'])&& isset($_POST['description'])){}
```

But when I check the vardump it is empty and is only receiving 1 input and it is the membership input

Any ideas What I am doing wrong? I did some research and it said I needed to change the size of the Post so PHP can handle it but this only happens if you receive some data, I am not receiving any data, other forms I have work just fine, the only difference is the enctype. Do I have to add the name property, I thought I access the values using the ID, at least I did this on the other forms but doing the Post with jquery

below is the output of the var dump and the file contents

> CONTENT_TYPE: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarya1VR5jhYCMXhari4
>   DATA:
>   string(0) ""
>   array(1) {["membership"]=> string(1) "3"}
>   array(0) {}

Comment: post your html form also

Comment: Do all your inputs have name properties? The names are the properties that $_POST will use to identify the data.

Comment: @MichaelvE you were right I need to add the names, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to add the attribute name to your inputs. Please, check: https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_forms.asp

I also notice that you are uploading a file, this post will also help you and provide some valuable information to you: https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_file_upload.asp